# C++14 using auto keyword in a method's definition

Tags: c++, parameters, c++14, auto

I have several `std::unordered_maps`. They all have an `std::string` as their key and their data differs. I want to make a csv string from a given map's keys because that data needs to be sent over the wire to a connected client. At the moment I have a method for each individual map. I wanted to make this generic and I came up with the following :

```
std::string myClass::getCollection(auto& myMap) {
    std::vector <std::string> tmpVec;
    for ( auto& elem : myMap) {
        tmpVec.push_back(elem.first);
    }
    std::stringstream ss;
    for ( auto& elem : tmpVec ) {
        ss << elem <<',';
    }
    std::string result=ss.str();
    result.pop_back(); //remove the last ','
    return result;
}
```

I compile with gcc 6.1.0 and -std=c++14 using eclipse and it compiles but it doesn't link.
The linker complains about undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::getCollection(someMap);`

Regardless of the map data and the way I call it, it always tells me :

> `Invalid arguments ' Candidates are: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>> getCollection() '`

How do I solve this?

Comment: `std::string myClass::getCollection(auto& myMap)` is not valid syntax. Specifically, `auto` is not a valid parameter type for a member function.

Comment: is what I'm trying to accomplish possible using another approach then? I thought it was possible to use auto as a parameter in c++14... apparently I'm wrong then...

Comment: "*I thought it was possible to use auto as a parameter in c++14...*" Only for lambdas. "*is what I'm trying to accomplish possible using another approach then?*" Yes, just use normal templates: `template<typename MapT> std::string myClass::getCollection(MapT& myMap)`

Comment: Using `auto` in function parameters is currently non-standard, but might get into the language in C++20. It's called an "abbreviated function template" and I think it's part of the Concepts proposal. GCC provides it as an extension currently; if you compile with `-pedantic` it'll fail.

Comment: Since 'auto' parameter is just like a template param, you should define (not just declare) the member function in the header file - otherwise the definition won't get instantiated in some translation units.

Comment: Missing a [mcve] for the link error...

Comment: @Marc Glisse - I'll make one and add it to the question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As in C++14 `auto` parameters are only allowed in lambdas (as per @ildjarn's comment), you can just develop a **function template**, templateized on the map type, e.g.:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class myClass {
...

template <typename MapType>
std::string getCollection(const MapType& myMap) {
    std::vector <std::string> tmpVec;
    for ( const auto& elem : myMap) {
        tmpVec.push_back(elem.first);
    }
    std::stringstream ss;
    for ( const auto& elem : tmpVec ) {
        ss << elem <<',';
    }
    std::string result=ss.str();
    result.pop_back(); //remove the last ','
    return result;
}
```

Note also the addition of `const` for some *const*-correctness.

Moreover, why not just building the output string directly using the string stream object, without populating an *intermediate* `vector<string>` (which is more code, more potential for bugs, more overhead, less efficiency)?

And, since you are just interested in using the string stream as an *output* stream, using `ostringstream` instead of `stringstream` is better as it's more efficient and communicates your intent better.

```
#include <sstream>  // for std::ostringstream
#include <string>   // for std::string
...

template <typename MapType>
std::string getCollection(const MapType& myMap) {
    std::ostringstream ss;
    for (const auto& elem : myMap) {
        ss << elem.first << ',';
    }
    std::string result = ss.str();
    result.pop_back(); // remove the last ','
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your improvements. I keep having the same linking problems... undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::

Comment: Do you have the template method implemented inline in some header, or at least accessible by your client's code? Do you include all the required headers (e.g. `<sstream>`, `<vector>`, `<string>`, your map collection's headers)?

Comment: yes, I have  template <typename MapType>
 std::string getCollection(MapType& myMap); in my header file that is included in the cpp where the template/function is and also included in another header where the class's method gets called

Comment: @ZoOl007: The function template must be *implemented* inline in a header file if you want to call it in another header or .cpp file. It's not like for ordinary non-templated functions, that you can declare in a header and implement in a separate .cpp file.

Comment: ok, it works now... this is new for me... so, all templated functions are best put completely in a header file then? Confusing difference. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 7):

Why not just use a template?

```
template <typename TMap>
std::string myClass::GetCollection(TMap &myMap) {
    std::vector <std::string> tmpVec;
    for ( auto& elem : myMap) {
        tmpVec.push_back(elem.first);
    }
    std::stringstream ss;
    for ( auto& elem : tmpVec ) {
        ss << elem <<',';
    }
    std::string result=ss.str();
    result.pop_back(); //remove the last ','
    return result;
}
```

Your method is exactly the same, but instead of the `auto` keyword, we use template function syntax to handle the type inference.

Comment: Maybe mention that `auto` cannot be used as parameter type to a function?

Comment: Thank you. I'm still having the same undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::

Comment: @ZoOl007 : That is a namespace, so you _must_ be leaving something off the end. The important part in this case... ;-]

Answer (score 6):

`auto` parameters are [only allowed in lambdas](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp14-language#generic-lambdas) in C++14.

Probably this is since in an classic function like yours you could have declared a function template (which is basically what happens in the lambda case) while lambdas can't be templates.